# xsl server variable returns null

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, web-parts, request.servervariables

xsl server variable URL returns null. I tried all the other server variable and they all returns nulls.

Is there anything I need to do (like in IIS or web.config) in order for xsl to show server variables? (i am working on webpart in sharepoint).

1. `<ParameterBinding Name="URL" Location="ServerVariable(URL)" DefaultValue=""/>`
2. `<xsl:param name="$URL"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Your XSL parameter should be declared with the name "URL", not "$URL":

```
<xsl:param name="URL" />
```